# Why is UIWebView not loading data from cache on iOS4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, uiwebview

Hey guys in my APP i have created custom class for cache by inheriting NSURLCache class and implemented required methods to pass my local files data as cached data.[I have done it same as this tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html)

In my APP there is one refresh button,on click of it i have to refresh the current page for this i have done following to load locally stored CSS and JS files

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (isGoingToRefresh) {
        [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
        isGoingToRefresh = NO;
        return YES;
    }
    NSString *path = [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.pathname"];
    path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]configurationFile]objectForKey:@"RootURL"],path];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
    if ([path isEqualToString:[[request URL]absoluteString]]) {
        [self showRefreshLoader];
        isGoingToRefresh = YES;
        NSURLRequest *localRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[request URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:240] ;
        [webView loadRequest:localRequest];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
```

}

Above code is loading data from cache by calling following NSURLCache method -

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

But on iOS4 webView not calling above NSURLCache method.

I am not getting why please suggest me some good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

try using to make your request

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed 
                                        timeoutInterval:60];
```

Comment: it is same as previous solution(whatever i have done )..., i tried it not working thanks for reply ...

Comment: It's a different cache policy.

Comment: on iOS 5 it is working for cache policy  NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad but not working on iOS4, i have tried 1/2 more, no one solved my problem now i am planing to change the way of caching.......